# Run Jquery Function on page load, not on image click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jquery plugin and right now it only runs when the button is click. How can I make it run on page load? Or maybe 3 seconds after page load.

```
<div class="classysocial"></div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".classysocial").each(function() {
         new ClassySocial(this);
      });
   });
</script>
```

EDIT: here is the JS for the plugin:
http://pastebin.com/Ct6asnYy

Comment: I dont know what ClassySocial is, but it should run on page load, and not on any click if this is the only code

Comment: This code should already run on page load. I'm willing to bet the problem is elsewhere, perhaps with the library itself.

Comment: here is the js file: http://pastebin.com/Ct6asnYy

Answer (score 3):

I guess `Classysocial` is some plugin that binds `onclick` event to the button.

If You can't access the plugin code, the hotfix would be to trigger onclick programatically, like:

```
 $("your_button_selector").click()
```

To achieve delay, take a look at jQuery `.delay()` method.
Check also Javascript's native `setTimeout` and decide which one suits your needs.